# issues retreiving users access to a folder in SharePoint with phpspo

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've been developing an integration with SP via phpSpo, and I've already managed to achieve many things - creating directories, adding and removing users with both edit and view-only rights, but I've now been stuck on an issue for a few days and I can't seem to find a way out.

I want to retrieve the list of users that have access to a speficic directory in ShaperPoint.
Since I didn't find any tutorial on this, I found a powershell script that works, and I tried to rewrite it on phpspo.

the powershell function is this:

```
Function Get-SPOFolderPermission([String]$SiteURL, [String]$FolderRelativeURL) {
    Try {
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
      
        #Get the Folder
        $Folder = $Ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderRelativeURL)
        $Ctx.Load($Folder)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
        #Get permissions assigned to the Folder
        $RoleAssignments = $Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments
        $Ctx.Load($RoleAssignments)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
        #Loop through each permission assigned and extract details
        $PermissionCollection = @()
        Foreach ($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments) { 
            $Ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.Member)
            $Ctx.executeQuery()
 
            #Get the User Type
            $PermissionType = $RoleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType
 
            #Get the Permission Levels assigned
            $Ctx.Load($RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            $PermissionLevels = ($RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
             
            #Get the User/Group Name
            $Name = $RoleAssignment.Member.Title # $RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName
 
            #Add the Data to Object
            $Permissions = New-Object PSObject
            $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty Name($Name)
            $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty Type($PermissionType)
            $Permissions | Add-Member NoteProperty PermissionLevels($PermissionLevels)
            $PermissionCollection += $Permissions
        }
        Return $PermissionCollection
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Getting Folder Permissions!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

the core of my php function is this

```
try{
    // folder contains the Folder item I want to get info about
    $listItem = $folder->getListItemAllFields()->get()->executeQuery();
    $ras = $listItem->getRoleAssignments()->get()->executeQuery();
    $oDebug->AddDebugLine(__LINE__,"HERE","",__FILE__,__FUNCTION__  );
    // $ras should countain the Role Assignment Collection returned by the getRoleAssignment call
    foreach($ras as $ra){
        // loop over all RoleAssignments
        // get the principal member info of the RA
        $member = $ra->getMember()->executeQuery();
        $name =  $member->getTitle();
        // extract the Title of the member (i.e. the name of the user
        $userType = $member->getPrincipalType();
        // this should return an integer that indicates the mode
        $i++;
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    // this is never triggered
    continue;
}
$oDebug->AddDebugLine(__LINE__,$i,"FOUND",__FILE__,__FUNCTION__ );
echo  $i . "\n";
```

It all looks simple and it should work, but it doesn't!
At the end, i = 4, which is correct for this folder, because the powershell script run on the same directory finds 4 users, but both `$name` and `$userType` are empty!

I already tried to add a `->get()->executeQuery()` after `getTitle()` and/or `getPrincpalType()`, but that exited with an exception.
I also tried to remove the `->executeQuery()` after `$ra->getMember()`, but the result doesn't change (no errors, still 4 users, no name and no usertype).

Any suggestion on how I can fix this?
what am I doing wrong?

thanks for your help

Simone

Comment: Inside your foreach-loop - is $member returning anything? I've never used PHP but on your first two calls, you are using "->get()". Do you need to be using that inside the loop to? $ra->getMember()->get()->executeQuery();

Comment: thanks for the feedback, Chirstoffer. yes, $member returns an object; I tried to dump it, but it's a huge and inintelligible structure. as I wrote at the end of the post above, yes I tried any permutation, with or without get() and executeQuery() inside the look. I don't get any output in any case